# Spring Prometheus metric is missing status code

Tags: spring, kotlin, prometheus, metrics

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.5 with latest micrometer-registry-prometheus dependency and Kotlin 1.6.21.

In my `application.yaml` I have

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health, info, prometheus
```

And in `RestController` I have something like this

```
@GetMapping
@Timed(value = "search_something")
fun search(): ResponseEntity<SomeDto> { return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.Ok, SomeDto() }
```

I would like to aggregate metrics by status code, however this is what I see under `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint

```
search_something_seconds_count{class="org.example.TestController",exception="none",method="search",} 1.0
```

How can I add http status code to this metric?

Also, another question - is there a way to automatically capture all incoming requests without explicitly annotating each endpoint with `@Timed` ?

Comment: check here please : https://community.traefik.io/t/http-response-code-metrics-in-prometheus-output/12396